# How to reverse *.pkg file? This is a firmware file of a router

Tags: firmware

I am a newbi for reversing engineering.
I am going to reversing a firmware file. (*.pkg)
I could find many tutorials for reversing *.bin, but I can't find any tutorials for reversing *.pkg file.
And I don't have the router device yet, so I can't dump a bin file from the device now.

**I wanna know how to reversing *.pkg and what is the best tool for this reversing work.**

====================================================

PS:
This pkg file was not a firmware, it's a MacOS install file.
But I downloaded my router firmware, it's also *.pkg.
And it works well with firmware reversing tools.
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: A .pkg file is just a file with that extension. Without knowing the file content this question can not be answered.

Comment: As I said, this is a firmware file. I wanna reverse and view firmware contents, so I asked this question. Sorry for my stuppid question. But I want you to help me please.

Comment: There is no standardized format for firmware files. It could be compressed, encrypted, or whatever. How should we know what file you want to reverse? Why don't you apply one of the "bin tutorials" on your pkg file and see what happens?

Comment: You are right. I also think *.pkg is not a standard format for firmware, so I need help for this. You means my *.pkg  can be a compressed, encrypted file of real firmware file, right? I will check my file again soon.  Thank you for your advice.

Comment: I have had a case where the file was renamed as .pkg to make it more obvious as a packet. In my case it was a tar.gz archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*.pkg is also firmware file format. 
 But it's not standard firmware format, it's custom format. You can use unpack tools like *.bin files.

Answer (score 1):

PKGs are (usually) installer files for macOS. If this is a normal Mac package, you can use a tool called [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com). However, this may not be the case. If you know the router brand, we may be able to help you more if you tell us the name.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no “standard” format for `.pkg` firmware files.

Most likely it’s some custom format used by the vendor, so look for a vendor-specific tutorial or simply analyze it as unknown format (i.e. `.bin`)